# Iteratively assigning values to C Structures

Tags: c, enums, struct, iteration

I have a structured defined as

```
typedef struct{
char string1
char string2
int number1
char string3
}structure1
```

and want to assign the values to string1,string2,number1,string3 in a loop like this

```
structure1 bob
for(int i = 0,i<=4,i++)
{
bob.i = assigned value
}
```

now I understand that code above in it's generic form will only work for integers as you can't just go string = string for assignment, but the same problem arises as I don't know how to reference the  values inside a struct without specifically naming them one by one. for strings there will be a second assignment relying on the i index to work out if it's a integer or string at the time so it can perform the assignment. I was thinking something along the lines of enum's but I've never used them in a practical sense before, just theoretical.

Comment: This does not make sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: basically I have to parse a file, it has 6 pieces of information per line, this is put into a structure as defined similar to above.
in total there are about 10 lines.

so I need to create a structure array, and then inside that, read the file parse the lines, assign those values back into the structure, of which I'd rather do iteratively if possible

Comment: It looks pretty much like [Reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) which requires a higher level language.

Comment: @Hoang: Then just past the structure as read buffer and it will be filled during read operation.

Comment: If you know the exact length of each line, then you could just copy the data into the structure byte by byte, but you probably don't. Then you have to either populate each field manually, or use a char** array instead of a struct (which will require conversion to relevant data types when used).

Comment: You havent accepted an answer for this question yet :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible in C. The closest to that would be calculating field offsets and then using them to assign values:

```
int fieldOffset[4];

structure1 base;

fieldOffset[0] = (char*)&base.string1 - (char*)&base;
fieldOffset[1] = (char*)&base.string2 - (char*)&base;
fieldOffset[2] = (char*)&base.number1 - (char*)&base;
fieldOffset[3] = (char*)&base.string3 - (char*)&base;

structure1 structYouWantToAssign;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    *((char*)&structYouWantToAssign + fieldOffset[i]) = assignedValue;
}
```

**Warning**: this code is just to demonstrate it is possible to assign fields without their name, but you should **not** use it!

Comment: I was just discussing it on another forum, and a member said it may be possible, to do with pointers assuming the entire struct was of the same type, instead of a mish mash of char and int.
that does seem like a rather unsafe way of going about it(not the points, the example you posted, but it makes theoretical sense at least)

Comment: This is why I cast everything to `char*` to avoid problems, and it does work. However you will be unable to assign the proper value type just basing yourself on `i` (since you need to know the underlying type size).

Comment: well all my char assignments are sized at creation
i.e
char bob[10]
char bob2[20]
int days

Comment: @HPM - If all the struct members are of the same type, this is much easier solved with an array!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's not possible in C. It's be really cool, but nothing of the sort is in the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a slightly different approach. Wanting to do that implies you're initialising them in which case you could do this:

```
#define STRUCT_DEF {"default", "another", 1234, "the last string" }
...
structure1 Variable = {"default", "another", 1234, "the last string"};
```

(that's assuming you meant char string1[STR_LEN] rather than just a single char.)

Alternatively you could try redefining your structure with arrays inside:

```
typedef struct{
char string[NUM_STRINGS][STR_LENGTH];
int number1;
}structure1
```

That way you can address the strings in a loop without naming each individually.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function which assigns to the member:-

```
void BobAssign(struct* s, int i, void * value);
```